# React - toggle in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle visiblity of a div in a stateless component like this:

```
    const playerInfo = (props) => {
      let isPanelOpen = false;
      return (
          <div onClick={() => isPanelOpen = !isPanelOpen }>Toggle</div>
          {isPanelOpen && <div className="info-panel">
            {props.children}
          </div>}
      );
    };
```

I see that the value of `isPanelOpen` changes to `true`, but the panel is not being shown. I assume that is because this is the stateless function that doesn't get called again, so once we return the jsx it will have the value of `false`, and won't update it later.
Is there a way of fixing this, and avoiding of pasing this single variable as props through 4 more parent stateless components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't tell React to re-render the UI by assigning new value directly to the variable (in your case you did `isPanelOpen = !isPanelOpen`).
The correct method is to use `setState`.

But you cannot do it in a stateless component, you must do it in a stateful component, so your code should looks like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class playerInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isPanelOpen: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.setState({isPanelOpen: !this.state.isPanelOpen})}>Toggle</div>
            {this.state.isPanelOpen && <div className="info-panel">
              {this.props.children}
          </div>}
        );
    }
}
```

### Explanation

Remember two things:
1) Your UI should only bind to `this.state.XXXX` (for stateful component) or `props.XXX` (for stateless component).
2) The only way to update UI is by calling `setState()` method, no other way will trigger React to re-render the UI.

#### But... how do I update stateless component since it doesn't have the `setState` method?

**ONE ANSWER**:The stateless component should be *contained* in another stateful component.

Example

Let's say your stateless component is called `Kid`, and you have another stateful component called `Mum`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Mum extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isHappy: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({isHappy: true})}>Eat</button>
                <Kid isHappy={this.state.isHappy}/>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

const Kid = (props) => (props.isHappy ? <span>I'm happy</span> : <span>I'm sad</span>);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using useState hooks like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

            function playerInfo () {

        const [panel, setPanel] = useState(false);

        function toggleButton () {
            if(!panel) setPanel(true);
            else setPanel(false);
            }

        return (
            <div>
            <button onClick={toggleButton}>Toggle</div>
            panel ? {this.props.children} : null;
            </div>}
              );
            };

    export default playerInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that is because this is the stateless function that doesn't get called again

Basically, the only way to re-render component is to change state or props. :)

So when you change a local variable, React doesn't get notified about it and doesn't start [reconcilation](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#reconciliation).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with native Javascipt  otherwise in React you can not do this with stateless Component :)

```
const playerInfo = (props) => {
    let isPanelOpen = false;
    return ( <
        div onClick = {
            () => {
                if (document.getElementsByClassName("info-panel")[0].style.display == 'none') {
                    isPanelOpen = true;
                    document.getElementsByClassName("info-panel")[0].style.display = '';
                } else {
                    isPanelOpen = false;
                    document.getElementsByClassName("info-panel")[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        } > Toggle < /div> <
        div className = "info-panel" > {
            this.props.children
        } <
        /div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 16.8 of React you can handle this for stateless components using a hook - in this case `useState`. In it's simplest form it can be implemented like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const PlayerInfo = (props) => {
  const [showPanel, togglePanel] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => togglePanel(!showPanel) }>Toggle</div>
   {showPanel && (
     <div className="info-panel">
        {props.children}
      </div>
   )}
   </div>
  );
};

export default PlayerInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional component will not re-render unless a previous parent's state changes and passes down updated properties that propagate down to your functional component. You can pass an onClick handler in from a stateful parent and call this from your stateless component when its onClick is triggered. The parent will control the toggling of the display and pass it in as a prop to the child (see snippet below).

To architect this, you should determine if your HOC (higher order component) should be in charge of UI state. If so, then it can make the determination if its child component should be in an open state or not and then pass that as a property to the child state. If this is a component that should open and close independent of the world around it, then it should probably have its own state. For example, if you are making a tabbed widget, it should probably be controlling its own open and closed states.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state= {
    isOpen: false
  }
  
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <YourComponent isOpen={this.state.isOpen} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const YourComponent = ({isOpen, handleClick} = props) => {
  const onClick = () => {
    if (handleClick) {
      handleClick();
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
      {isOpen ? 
        <h2>it is open</h2>
       :
        <h2>it is closed</h2>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If your major concern is about passing properties/methods down to too many components, you could create a [pure component](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html) which will give you access to state but not all the overhead of a React Component subclass. You could also look into using a state management tool like Redux.